# Casting date in Nodejs mssql does not work

Tags: node.js, sql-server, tedious

I am trying to remove timestamp from a data column. I can do that in SQL Server Management Studio doing:

```
 select CAST(GETDATE() as date)
```

Now, when I try to do the same thing using `Nodejs-MSSQL`  library I get the time stamp as well:

```
await pool.query(` select CAST(GETDATE() as date)`)
```

[image]

Can someone please explain how this is even possible?

Comment: Does Javascript have a pure date class?

Comment: connector probably parse the date object. just make sure to handling the timezone then it should be fine.